# Difference between Application Settings methods in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I found these 2 articles about Application Settings, one is setting it up through the Visual Studio ui - the other is about setting the application settings up programatically.

[Add or Remove Application Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Create Application Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171565(v=vs.110).aspx)

It looks like they do the same thing, but in a different way. Would there be any difference or advantage between using the ui through Visual Studio to add different settings versus if I created my own `UserSettings` class that inherits `ApplicationSettingsBase`? If they are different, how would I use one differently than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both do the same thing for creating settings, and the only reason (other than personal preference) for choosing one over the other is if you want to modify any settings at run rime.

If your settings won't be changed, then the VS UI is the easiest way to do it. If you want to be able to change them at run time, then as you can see from the second link, you can change and persist your settings in code.